# operador between en mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

sabeis si se puede utilizar algun tipo de operador comodin, para que esta sentencia devuelva todos los valores cuando las variables `$condicionFechaDesde,$condicionFechaHasta` esten vacias? Este es mi codigo. Lo que quiero es que cuando las variables `$condicionFechaDesde,$condicionFechaHasta` no esten definidas o tengan un valor vacio, la sentencia sql devuelva todos los valores en la condicion between.

```
if(!isset($_POST["fechaDesde"]) or $_POST["fechaDesde"]=="")
{   
    $condicionFechaDesde="%";
}
else
{   
    $condicionFechaDesde=$fechaDesde."%";            
}
if(!isset($_POST["fechaHasta"]) or $_POST["fechaHasta"]=="")
{   
    $condicionFechaHasta="%";
}
else
{   
    $condicionFechaHasta=$fechaHasta."%";            
}
            $sentencia = $db->prepare("select idVenta from ventas where enviado=? and pagado=? and fecha between ? and ? group by idVenta order by fecha asc");
            $sentencia->bind_param("iiss",$condicionEnviado,$condicionPagado,$condicionFechaDesde,$condicionFechaHasta);
```

Comment: Suena a que debes escribir 2 sentencias, una para cada caso.

Comment: `...and fecha between ? and ? OR fecha=''...` no funciona?

Comment: ¿Cuando estén vacías donde, en la base de datos? Y, ¿qué entiendes por *vacías*: una cadena vacía, NULL, o no coincidencia en un JOIN?

Comment: *"Cuando las variables ... no están definidas ...  devuelva ... los valores en la condicion between"*, Pero si las condiciones en el between son las variables no definidas. ¿que devuelva donde las fechas no están definidas?.

Comment: con dos sentencias funciona bien, pero yo esperaba que hubiese una forma de hacerlo todo con una sola sentencia. Por vacia entiendo que vale "". Me explico mejor, lo que pretendo es que cuando las variables no esten definidas o estean vacias, desaparezca la condicion between, pero claro eso no es posible, entonces pensaba en que hubiese algun comodin para especificar en el between que devolviese todos los valores sin tener en cuenta el "desde" y el "hasta"

Comment: Lo que dices no es buena idea. Más bien deberías construir tu instrucción SQL verificando el estado de las variables, de modo que si alguna variable no tuviese datos no sea incluida en la consulta. Eso de mandar datos a lo loco o vacíos no tiene mucho sentido, controla la instrucción SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes añadir a la consulta el betwen si las fechas no están vacias y sino no.

```
<?php
$consulta = "select idVenta from ventas where enviado=? and pagado=?"; //La consulta base ( se le añadira el betwen si se envian fechas)
$array_valores = array($condicionEnviado, $condicionPagado); //Los valores base (enviado, pagado). En el caso de que se hayan enviado fecha, lo cambiaremos más adelante.
$tipo_valores = "ii"; //El tipo de valores de $array_valores para el bind_param
if (!isset($_POST["fechaDesde"]) || $_POST["fechaDesde"] == "" || !isset($_POST["fechaHasta"]) ||  $_POST["fechahasta"] == "") {
    //Aquí no se han enviado ambas fechas o se han enviado vacias.
} else {
    //Aquí se han enviado fechas asi que le añadimos a la consulta el betwen
    $consulta .= " and fecha between ? and ?";
    $tipo_valores = "iiss";
    $array_valores = array($condicionEnviado, $condicionPagado, $condicionFechaDesde, $condicionFechaHasta);
}
$consulta .= " order by fecha asc"; //Añadimos a la consulta el order
$sentencia = $db->prepare($consulta);
$sentencia->bind_param($tipo_valores, ...$array_valores);
```

Lo de los "..." se llama Variadic Functions y puedes leer más aquí.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Esto es solamente orientativo y en ningún caso deberias de copiarlo tal cual a tu proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

La alternativa es mandar fechas extremas de reemplazo:

```
$sentencia->bind_param( "iiss"
                      , $condicionEnviado
                      , $condicionPagado
                      , ( $condicionFechaDesde !== ''
                        ? $condicionFechaDesde
                        : '1970-01-01 00:00:00'
                        )
                      , ( $condicionFechaHasta !== ''
                        ? $condicionFechaHasta
                        : '2038-01-18 13:14:07'
                        )
                      );
```